# Spring-FW in VScode => Actulator view

Tags: spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I'm currently checking out the Spring framework and I try to rebuild the Tutorial on [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support-tutorial.html#actuator). All works so far, but the step of the actuator view (health view) I'm not really able to reproduce with VSCode. Did I miss something here? Or is there currently simply no support (extension) for VSCode?

Greetings!

Comment: That tutorial is based on IntelliJ and the actuator overview is a intellij feature, so no that won;t be available in VSCode (unless someone wrote a plugin for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking for some plugins, VSCode doesn't seem to support the actuator component. Thank also to @M.Deinum.